# append text javascript,don't get values

Tags: php, javascript

This is the code in append input box in java script,i don't get there values in the inputbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addInput()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("inputs");
    x.innerHTML += "<input type=\"text\"  name=\"box[]\" id=\"box[]\"/>";
    i++;
}
function getdata()
{

}
</script>


<input type="button" onmousedown="addInput();" value="add" />
<input type="button" value="getvalues" onclick="getdata()"  />
<div id="inputs"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing should work, but another way of doing it is (slightly more efficient):

```
 function addInput()  {
    var input = createTextInput({
      "type": "text", 
      "name": "box[0]", 
      "id":"box[]",
      "value": "This is a value"
    });
    document.getElementById("inputs").appendChild(input);
 }

 // warning: just to be safe, don't pass any option object that extends any 
 // browser's native object or built in objects.
 function createTextInput(options)  {
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    for(key in options) { 
      i[key] = options[key];
    }
    return i
 }

 function getValues() {
    var div = document.getElementById("inputs");
    var values = [];
    var textBoxes = div.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0, len = textBoxes.length; i < len; i++) {
       var box = textBoxes[i];
       if(box && box.name === "box[]") {values.push(box.value);}
    }
    return values;
 }
```

There are other ways of doing it, e.g. using jQuery, its much simpler and less verbose, but this is just the plain 'ol js way

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of passing attributes as individual parameters, we can pass an object with attribute names,values as key/value pairs (named arguments) and inside the function we can iterate and set the attributes.

var input = createTextInput({id: 'box[]', name: 'box[]'})
inside createTextInput(attrs), for(var attr in attrs) {/*set attribute*/}

Comment: @jagadeesh Added a function to get values

Answer (score 0):

The code itself should work. Try this: copy addInput from the function declaration to the callin the onmousedown.
For some reason the call from mousedown is not recognized. My JS-engine tells me, that addInput (like written in mousedown) was not found.

Comment: i want to get the values of the input box ,input box should be declared as array box[]

Comment: The ID has to be unique, so box[] for every input is not allowed. boxes = document.getElementsByName('box[]') should be possible. And then boxes[0].value

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of the input fields, assign a name to the input fields and you can access it through form. When there are multiple fields of the same name, the fields will be returned as an array:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function addInput() 
{ 
    var x = document.getElementById("inputs"); 
    x.innerHTML += "<input type=\"text\"  name=\"userNames\"/>"; 

} 
function getdata() 
{
    var form = document.forms['myForm'];
    //To handle single/multiple input elements
    var names = !form.userNames[0] ? [form.userNames] : form.userNames;
    var nameValues = [];
    for(var index = 0; index < names.length; index++) {
        nameValues[index] = names[index].value;
    }
    return nameValues;
} 


</script> 

<form name="myForm">
<input type="button" onmousedown="addInput();" value="add" /> 
<input type="button" value="getvalues" onclick="alert(getdata())"  /> 
<div id="inputs"></div> 
</form>
```